# Dúvida sobre negativação em resposta dada

Tags: suporte

No caso referente à pergunta [Ajuda no regex splitar string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/480262/ajuda-no-regex-splitar-string), gostaria de ter um *feedback* de vocês do motivo para o *downvote* em minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/480284/189752) e, caso possível, uma crítica sobre como melhorar minhas futuras respostas baseado no que deixei a desejar aqui.

Pontos a considerar:

- Mencionei a versão do `bash` em que meu código de exemplo foi executado
- Postei um exemplo totalmente reproduzível por si só que resolve o problema levantado
- Apresentei detalhes sobre quais seriam os dados relevantes à extrair de acordo com a solicitação do autor
- Fiz a descrição detalhada da lógica implementada na expressão regular proposta em edição da resposta

EDIT: Mais um ponto de consideração adicionado.

Comment: Sobre a resposta, só quem negativou para dizer, mas a pergunta foi fechada pelas razões que mencionei nos comentários lá. Minha sugestão é evitar perguntas do tipo "faz pra mim" (mesmo que seja sem intenção do autor), muitas vezes acaba atraindo um "olho torto" nas respostas (não que isso seja necessariamente motivo pra negativação).

Comment: @Bacco Aproveitando seu comentário, uma pergunta então: para uma pergunta inadequada que foi fechada pela mesma razão, as respostas deveriam ser qualificadas como violação de alguma das regras?

Comment: Eu particularmente considero meio que como um "mau investimento" apenas, já respondi muita coisa pra ajudar o autor e fechei o post em seguida, mas é muito individual a interpretação. A pergunta estava aberta, você respondeu, tudo dentro do funcionamento normal do site.

Comment: @Bacco Independente de ser um "mau investimento" ou não, é irritante dedicar seu tempo e energia à resposta de uma pergunta com qualidade para ela sofrer múltiplos *downvotes* sem qualquer satisfação. Vejo isso como um problema recorrente desta comunidade e infelizmente deve desencorajar um pouco a participação aqui.

Comment: Aí já foge um pouco do foco. Eu acho mais desencorajador ver +1 em porcaria, e é o que mais tem ultimamente no site.  -1 em resposta desconta só 2 pontinhos do autor, se a resposta for boa é natural que em pouco tempo os positivos compensem os negativos a ponto destes serem desprezíveis. Eu, como quase todos os usuários com tempo de site já recebi uma série de negativos, alguns até por vingança (digo isso pq em alguns casos de abuso a autoria é verificável), com o tempo a gente acaba desencando. Mantenho a sugestão de evitar posts meio ambíguos, em todo caso, se quiser evitar riscos.

Comment: Um bom exemplo é moderar o site. Pessoalmente só gera dor de cabeça e ataques de umas criaturas quase irracionais (talvez seja um "mau investimento" de tempo, mas o perfil de quem ataca é até prova de que o trabalho vai bem kkk). Só que a gente faz pq acredita em alguns princípios, então faz parte. Pense do outro lado, a resposta foi aceita e já compensou os pontos. Quem perguntou saiu com solução, você saiu com saldo  positivo, a pergunta nao agrega muito pro coletivo mas já foi fechada, saiu todo mundo ganhando no fim. Não tem solução perfeita, o importante é achar  o ponto de equilíbrio.

Comment: @Bacco Concordo, acho que chegamos a um consenso. Difícil ter uma resposta definida para esta questão, até porque provavelmente quem deu voto negativo não deve aparecer aqui da mesma forma como não quis se expor na questão original; então, acho que posso deletar ou, se você preferir, pode fechar ou responder esta pergunta.

Comment: Eu acho a discussão saudável, eu sugeriria deixar aqui mais um tempo até para atrair visibilidade pra resposta. Quando quiser pode usar o link "remover" abaixo dessa pergunta aqui. De repente quem negativou pode resolver comentar (ou outras pessoas trazerem mais.pontos de vista).

Comment: Olá Rfroes87, não sei se esse foi o motivo dos negativos, com excessão da sua resposta, as demais contêm erros sobre o uso de "ponto", por exemplo a do marcelo, `(.chi.zst)`, a propria pergunta tem uma regex incorreta. Sua regex não me parece incorreta, mas sua resp não tem explicação nenhuma, a pergunta assim é um helpdesk, e da forma que você respondeu também ficou como helpdesk, não estou afirmando que foi o motivo dos downvotes, mas é bem mais provavel, o objetivo do site é se tornar um repositório de conhecimento e não de dar coisas prontas, então esse pode ser o motivo dos downs.

Comment: ps: note que a pergunta também tem downvotes, geralmente isso mostra que a pergunta tem problemas e responder a perguntas problematicas geralmente é justificava para darem downvotes nas resps, o que pode ser ou não o motivo dos downs nas resps.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Achei que entrar em detalhes sobre o funcionamento da *regex* não era exatamente o foco da pergunta realizada, então preferi não carregar demais a resposta com informações que poderiam desvirtuar o tema; porém concordo que a refatoração completa da expressão regular pode gerar confusão sobre o que exatamente foi feito para corrigir o "mau funcionamento" da original. No mais, sim, estou ciente conforme já discutido aqui.

Comment: Não há problema em refatorar, ao contrário, muita coisa é melhor refatorada mesmo, a questão aqui, não é tema, não é se o código sugerido é diferente, a questão é se isso agrega conhecimento "para o repositório", ou se é simplesmente "suporte técnico" (helpdesk).

Comment: Certo. Em todo caso, fiz a edição da resposta destrinchando toda a *regex* proposta agora. Estarei fazendo qualquer alteração a mais que seja necessária caso tenham mais sugestões/críticas.

Comment: Tudo bem, que bom, mas só pra reforçar, o problema nem é tanto a resposta, mas sim a pergunta, ela é quem tem problemas, ela é quem acaba gerando esse tipo de situação. Veja bem, eu gosto muito de regex, muitas resps minhas são sobre isso, mas eu não respondo a perguntas que são mais helpdesk (já respondi algumas no passado, sempre me foi um mal negócio)

Comment: Independente de a pergunta ter problemas ou não, penso que uma resposta detalhada sobre um tópico ainda não abordado na comunidade [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) ainda pode servir como referência para uma pesquisa; já foi para mim e poderá ser para outros.

Comment: Tecnicamente abordado ele já foi diversas vezes, a abordagem é regex, o que é feito com ele geralmente é um compilado de diversos genéricos, que é basicamente entender como funciona o regex, portanto não é assunto novo, a questão é compreender a comunidade, compreender que temos anos aqui e que variar um pouquinho o códigos "comuns" adaptando a assunto específicos não vai tornar em assunto novo. Acho que os links q o Bacco lhe enviou devem dar uma luz melhor sobre tudo isso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Vamos ter que concordar em discordar, porque não me parece tão simples assim. A meu ver a pergunta aborda além de simplesmente *regex* por si só, como **usar** o mecanismo nativo de *regex* em `bash` dentro de condições e como **acessar os grupos capturados** com a variável *built-in* `BASH_REMATCH`.

Comment: Não acho que seja questão de discorda, só vim aqui tentar explicar o que é helpdesk, esse é o problema, simplesmente você só não esta familiarizado/acostumado com isso e portanto acaba vendo de uma outra forma, mas com o tempo talvez venha a entender aonde isso implica. De resto tudo ok, otimo domigo pra ti.

Comment: @Rfroes87 bem vindo ao SO-PT.